# Get parameter with double quotes using ParamStr()

Tags: delphi

So we have a 3rd party tool that we can't recompile but it uses this ParamStr(Index: Integer) to get command line arguments. I have tried everything I can find on the internet but it will not accept double quote character. I have used escape characters, etc, and created a test app to streamline the testing process and pin down the problem to this function.

Has anyone ever successfully passed double quotes through the command line parameters with this function?

Edit: I've posted my test app below. The processfromcommandline function is from the 3rd party library.

An example input for this would be like this:

```
"file1.adb file2.adb -p4THISISAPASSWORD"
```

The password is directly after the -p4. Our password is 'encrypted' and will look something more like this

```
file1.adb file2.adb -p4$/.;}{3"aG13Sz/"9@;.'
```

The test app outputs the string it gets using ShowMessage so you can see what delphi is doing.So my input would be something

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, clipbrd;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FParams:      Boolean;
    FAbort:       Boolean;
    FAppPath:     String;
    FLogPath:     String;
    FSuccess:     Boolean;
    FSourceFile:  String;
    FDestFile:    String;
    FParamCount:  Integer;
    FPassword4:   String;
    FKeyFile4:    String;
    FIVFile4:     String;
    FPassword5:   String;
    FKeyFile5:    String;
    FIVFile5:     String;
    procedure ProcessFromCommandLine;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure TForm1.ProcessFromCommandLine;
var bTo4: boolean;
    i,l,sz: Integer;
    s:      String;
    buf:    PAnsiChar;
begin
  bTo4 := False;
  for i := 1 to FParamCount do
   begin
    s := ParamStr(i);
    //s := getCommandLine;
    l := Length(s);
    if (i = 1) then
     FSourceFile := s
    else
    if (i = 2) and (Pos('-',s) = 0) then
     FDestFile := s
    else
    if (l > 3) and ((Pos('-p4',s) > 0) or (Pos('/p4',s) > 0)) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('uh' + s);
      FPassword4 := Copy(s,4,l-3);
      end
    else
    if (l > 3) and ((Pos('-p5',s) > 0) or (Pos('/p5',s) > 0)) then
      FPassword5 := Copy(s,4,l-3)
    else
    if (l > 3) and ((Pos('-i4',s) > 0) or (Pos('/i4',s) > 0)) then
      FIVFile4 := Copy(s,4,l-3)
    else
    if (l > 3) and ((Pos('-i5',s) > 0) or (Pos('/i5',s) > 0)) then
      FIVFile5 := Copy(s,4,l-3)
    else
    if (l > 3) and ((Pos('-k4',s) > 0) or (Pos('/k4',s) > 0)) then
      FKeyFile4 := Copy(s,4,l-3)
    else
    if (l > 3) and ((Pos('-k5',s) > 0) or (Pos('/k5',s) > 0)) then
      FKeyFile5 := Copy(s,4,l-3)
    else
    if (l > 2) and ((Pos('-l',s) > 0) or (Pos('/l',s) > 0)) then
      FLogPath := Copy(s,3,l-2)
    else
    if (s = '-4') then
      bTo4 := True
    else
    if (s = '-5') then
      bTo4 := False;
   end;
   Clipboard.AsText := FPassword4;
   ShowMessage(FPassword4);

end;
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
FParamCount := ParamCount;
  FParams := (FParamCount >= 1);
  if (FParams) then
   ProcessFromCommandLine;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I think you should add an example of the form of command line you want to process.  You say you've created a test app:  where is it?

Comment: _ParamStr_ is pretty much able to handle double quotes. It is even documented here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.ParamStr

"Use double quotation marks to wrap multiple words as one parameter (such as long file names containing spaces)."

Comment: I believe the OP's question is "how can I pass a string containing a double quote character to the application?", that is, "is it possible to make ParamStr(1) return a string containing a double quote character?".

Comment: @Uwe Not sure that's the point. How could you pass `foo"bar` as a param?

Comment: I've updated my thing to include the test app. The escape characters don't work. If you can prove me wrong that would be lovely but I have tried all the stuff listed on embarcaderos site and its to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, seems I mixed the terms "double quotation marks" and "double quotes".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ParamStr()` strips off `"` quote chars, even in an embedded quoted string, as in your example.  Thus

```
-p4$/.;}{3"aG13Sz/"9@;.'
```

Gets returned as

```
-p4$/.;}{3aG13Sz/9@;.'
```

This is hard coded behavior, you can't change it without altering the RTL's source code.

Even [Microsoft does the same thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/17w5ykft(v=VS.85).aspx) (see the 2nd and 4th examples), but at least it supports embedded `"` chars escaped as `\"`.  `ParamStr()` does not support any kind of escaping syntax at all!

In fact, `ParamStr()` has a few bugs <sup>1</sup> related to its quote handling (such as quoted empty parameters, `""`,  are ignored completely), so I would suggest using the Win32 `GetCommandLine()` to get the raw command line data and then parse it yourself however you want.

<sup>1: bug which were originally logged in the old Quality Central bug tracker, but were never ported to the newer Quality Portal bug tracker, and QC has since been decommissioned and is now offline.</sup>

Comment: Cool thanks for clearing that up. Unfortunately I can't change this code because our third party library refuses to give us support. But its good to know the problem is the function and not me. Thanks