# How to pass variable which contains double quote to Delphi executable in Cygwin?

Tags: delphi, cygwin

I am trying to get multiple parameters, each of which contains space separated tokens and is therefore quoted. However, when the whole parameter set is provided from Cygwin through a bash variable, Delphi does not recognize it.

Project1.sh

```
./Project1.exe "a b c d"
arg='"a b c d"'  
./Project1.exe $arg
```

Project1.pas

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ParamCount do begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ParamStr(I));
    if AnsiEndsText('\', ParamStr(I)) then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(ParamStr(I));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The expected entry is `a b c d`, as given by `./Project1.exe "a b c d"`.

Nevertheless, `./Project1.exe $arg` only gives `\a b c d\`.

Could you help to comment whether it is possible to get `a b c d` with a variable in Cygwin ?

Comment: what is the issue with `arg="a b c d"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get parameter with double quotes using ParamStr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525969/get-parameter-with-double-quotes-using-paramstr)

Comment: @matzeri I would like to have multiple parameters, each of which contains space separated values.

Answer (score 1):

When running `Project1.exe "a b c d"`, there is a single parameter whose value is just `a b c d`. The double-quotes are not part of the parameter value itself, they are merely delimiters to let the command line processor know that there is a single parameter with embedded spaces in it.

When running `Project1.exe $arg`, you are including double-quotes in the parameter value, so when passed on the command-line, they have to be escaped as `\"`, so you get the parameter passed as `"\"a b c d\""`. However, [Delphi's `ParamStr()` does not support `\"` escaping, and it strips off all `"` characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525969/). That is why you end up with a parameter value of `\a b c d\` instead.

If you just want a parameter value of `a b c d`, get rid of the double-quotes in your variable:

```
arg='a b c d'
```

Otherwise, you will have to call [`GetCommandLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) directly, and then parse it yourself manually, or use [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) (which [does support `\"` escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/parsing-cpp-command-line-arguments)).